# I tried to start up HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I tried to run `start-hbase.sh`. but...

```
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ cat ~/.bashrc | tail -n 2
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/:/usr/local/hbase/bin/:/usr/local/mahout/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$source ~/.bashrc
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$sh -x ./bin/start-hbase.sh 
...(skip)...
./start-hbase.sh: 53: [: unexpected operator
+ /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh --config /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf start zookeeper
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.jvm.java-7-oracle..bin.java
+ /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh --config /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf start master
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-dream-master-dream-VirtualBox.out
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.jvm.java-7-oracle..bin.java
+ /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh --config /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf --hosts /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf/regionservers start regionserver
starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-dream-1-regionserver-dream-VirtualBox.out
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.jvm.java-7-oracle..bin.java
+ /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase-daemons.sh --config /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf --hosts /usr/local/hbase/bin/../conf/backup-masters start master-backup
```

I observed `start-hbase.sh` that it tried to run shell of `/usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool` in fail.

I didn't sure that `hbase` why always throw exception.

```
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ /usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKServerTool
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.jvm.java-7-oracle..bin.java
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ ./bin/hbase shell
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.lib.jvm.java-7-oracle..bin.java
```

*But... I tried to use **sudo**. it maybe look work*

```
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ sudo ./bin/start-hbase.sh 
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-dream-VirtualBox.out
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.

dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ jps
2869 NameNode
3540 NodeManager
3403 ResourceManager
3237 SecondaryNameNode
3031 DataNode
5666 Jps

dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ sudo jps
5053 HQuorumPeer
2869 NameNode
3540 NodeManager
5857 Jps
3403 ResourceManager
3237 SecondaryNameNode
3031 DataNode

dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase$ sudo ./bin/hbase shell
2015-08-10 15:41:04,136 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.1, rd0a115a7267f54e01c72c603ec53e91ec418292f, Tue Jun 23 14:44:07 PDT 2015

hbase(main):001:0>
```

### My environment

- Linux dream-VirtualBox 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Java-7-oracle#1.7.0_80
- HBase-1.1.1

### My HBase setting

**conf/hbase-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>file:///usr/local/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hbase/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**~/.bashrc**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin/:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/:/usr/local/hbase/bin/
```

Would you please give me any help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you do "source ~/.bashrc" after setting export JAVA_HOME in bashrc

Comment: Yes, I had been update information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I not sure that why had some funny property of exec in /bin/hbase.

/bin/hbase:

> exec "$JAVA" -Dproc_$COMMAND -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p" $HEAP_SETTINGS $HBASE_OPTS $CLASS "$@"

Entity:

> exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java -DXXXXXX **/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle//bin/java** -Xmx1000m -DXXXXXX

I think that I needed delete `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle//bin/java`.

I observed line 217-229 in script of /bin/hbase.

```
217 #If avail, add Hadoop to the CLASSPATH and to the JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
218 # Allow this functionality to be disabled
219 if [ "$HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP" != "true" ] ; then
220   HADOOP_IN_PATH=$(PATH="${HADOOP_HOME:-${HADOOP_PREFIX}}/bin:$PATH" which hadoop 2>/dev/null)
221   if [ -f ${HADOOP_IN_PATH} ]; then
222     HADOOP_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$(HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH" ${HADOOP_IN_PATH} \
223                                org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.GetJavaProperty java.library.path 2>/dev/null)
224     if [ -n "$HADOOP_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH" ]; then
225       JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$(append_path "${JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH}" "$HADOOP_JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH")
226     fi
227     CLASSPATH=$(append_path "${CLASSPATH}" `${HADOOP_IN_PATH} classpath 2>/dev/null`)
228   fi
229 fi
```

That do something when HADOOP_PATH in PATH.

To explain why my user(dream) didn't run /bin/hbase but root was fine.

So, I had remove HADOOP_PATH in PATH. It seem work.

```
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ ./start-hbase.sh
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-dream-master-dream-VirtualBox.out
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ jps
22956 Jps
2869 NameNode
3540 NodeManager
3403 ResourceManager
3237 SecondaryNameNode
22722 HMaster
3031 DataNode
dream@dream-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ ./hbase shell
2015-08-10 23:33:44,016 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
Version 1.1.1, rd0a115a7267f54e01c72c603ec53e91ec418292f, Tue Jun 23     14:44:07 PDT 2015

hbase(main):001:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

add JAVA_HOME in hbase-env.sh

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

add given property in hbase-site.xml

```
<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>

<value>2181</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
#create zookeeperDir directory with permission 755
<value>/home/kishore/zookeeperDir</value>

</property>
```

make sure your zookeeper should be run on port 2181.

Comment: I followed your setting and it got same error message.  :-(

Comment: I think you should have to start zookeeper. Can you add your error in question?

Answer (score 0):

You ran **sh** interpreter with the command

```
sh -x ./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Use instead

```
./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

as you did in

```
sudo ./bin/start-hbase.sh
```

This automatically selects the script interpreter that may be different as the first line of **start-hbase.sh** says

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

The difference between these two ways is explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script

This solved the problem I had with

> **bin/start-hbase.sh: 51: [: unexpected operator**

I am using hbase-1.1.2 so the line may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with already running ZK service.
The error message/logs in a screenshot you attached clearly mentioned the problem :

```
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
```

I also faced the same problem, but when I stopped the ZK service everything works well. JPS started listing HMaster service.

I have used Java 8 and HBase 2.2.0